# MySql query to calculate number of peaks in moment

Tags: php, mysql

I need a help, I need to calculate number of active calls at the moment. This is my table:

```
+---------------------+---------+
| calldate            | billsec |
+---------------------+---------+
| 2013-05-14 09:40:30 |      29 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:31 |      24 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:31 |      30 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:33 |      20 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:34 |      21 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:35 |      30 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:36 |      30 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:37 |      30 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:37 |      25 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:39 |      22 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:39 |      19 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:40 |      22 |
| 2013-05-14 09:40:41 |      22 |
```

For example, If I want to calculate number of active calls in '2013-05-14 09:40:34', I should get 5 records, because for example, for the first row call is between '2013-05-14 09:40:30' and '2013-05-14 09:40:59' (calldate+billsec).

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about realtime check?

Comment: Why -1? Kindly explain.

Comment: I am sorry, what does (calldate+billsec) mean?

Comment: I can see where you're confused - apparently you haven't tried anything.

Comment: @FDL, you can't just simply `SELECT COUNT` the results. There is an interval required.

Comment: calldate+billsec is the end of call, in the text above I put it into brackets to know how I got 2013-05-14 09:40:59 result

Comment: I tried with this:

    SELECT calldate,peaks FROM (SELECT cl1.calldate as calldate,COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM cdr cl1  INNER JOIN cdr cl2 ON cl1.calldate BETWEEN cl2.calldate+0 AND cl2.calldate+cl2.billsec WHERE cl1.calldate between '2013-05-14 09:40:57' AND '2013-05-14 09:40:58' GROUP BY cl1.calldate) AS counts

Comment: Wait, so you mean if billsec is null then the call is not yet done?

Comment: @ChristianMark call has never be recorded into the database before it has been finished

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select count(*) from calls 
where '2013-05-14 09:40:34' between
  calldate and DATE_ADD(calldate,INTERVAL billsec SECOND)
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25847/2)

**Update:**
In order to see amounts for each calldate you can use subquery

```
select B.calldate
  ,(select count(*) from calls A
  where B.calldate between
    A.calldate and DATE_ADD(A.calldate,INTERVAL A.billsec SECOND)) numcalls
from calls B
group by B.calldate
```

[**SQLFIDDLE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e4ffde/11)

Comment: Thanks, its ok for this date, but how to make it incrementally, to calculate for every second between for example '2013-05-14 09:40:30' and '2013-05-14 09:40:34'. I can do it in the code, but its not a point. Thanks in advice

Comment: @NikolaRistivojevic added example for calculation for valid calldates. For incremental list you can first generate own list and use above query with it.